# 30% Of Requests are not processed by RestFul Service deployed on wildfly8.1.0.Final

Tags: rest, jmeter, performance-testing, wildfly-8, undertow

I am Using Undertow web server. 
Here is my undertow subsystem configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="limit-connections"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <connection-limit name="limit-connections" max-concurrent-requests="15000" queue-size="1000"/>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-       value="WildFly/8"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

IO Subsystem configuration (Hardware : 4 core processor and 16 gb RAM):

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
            <worker name="default" task-keepalive="300" io-threads="8" task-max-threads="64"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
```

My Test:

1. Using Jmeter, generated 3000 concurrent requests.
2. Among them 25 - 30 % requests failing by saying connection refused.
3. Server.log is not showing any errors.

Any idea how to acheive 0% failure rate for the requests that are generated.

Comment: Can you show your JMeter test plan and explain how the 3000 conc requests are performed ?

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE i Couldnt add screenshot since i have low reputation. I created Thread group and configured Thread Properties as below: 
1. NUMBER OF THREADS : 3000
2. RAMP UP PERIOD    : 1 Sec
3. LOOP COUNT        : 1

Comment: The HTTP requests that i am generating are POST and PAYLOAD is Protobuf

Comment: My question is about the test profile, can you show ThreadGroup config ? thx

Comment: Created Thread Group and configured Thread Properties as below: 1. NUMBER OF THREADS : 3000 2. RAMP UP PERIOD : 1 Sec 3. LOOP COUNT : 1

Comment: any feedback ? if ok you should accept and upvote, if not give more details

Answer (score 2):

If connection where refused it means undertow rejected them, it won't be logged in server.log, maybe in access.log but not sure.

You should try Ramping up slowly JMeter to see the limit where you start getting errors.

Also I suggest you increase number of iterations as this simulation does not seem to be realistic. What behaviour are you trying to reproduce ?

The fix will be to increase some values in IO subsytem:

- io-threads="8"
- task-max-threads="64"

Comment: If you see my io subsystem configuration mentioned in the question. I am already using the same. Based on the benchmark of undertow, it will support 1 million concurrent requests. But i am not seeing this happen and even with 3000 concurrent requests 30 % are connection refused

Comment: with 1000 requests it works fine and 0% failure, if i put more than that then i am seeing failures

Comment: So you are facing a Load issue which is what you can expect from a test. But you should really ensure your Test Profile is correct, in my experience it looks really strange. If answer is OK you should accept and upvote , thx

Comment: I feel its not a problem with Jmeter since it is able to generate 3000 threads. I understood about the configuration you mentioned in the answer but its not helping me and there is something else i need to tune wildfly.  If i didn't find solution for this i need to get rid of using undertow webserver and use other one. Thanks for your interest towards understanding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Undertow. About 30% of connections are refused when I access the server with java client.

When I use ab.exe (ApacheBench) I have 0% refused even if I use 1000 concurrent connections (seems this touches the limit on Windows 7).

The strange thing is that I have connection refused only when I use java client which opens the connections. I open 800 concurrent connections with java and many of them are refused. I tried the test even with socket timeout of 1000ms. Here is the fragment from my java client which opens the connections:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/testWeb/test2");
    URLConnection testConnection = url.openConnection();
    testConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
    testConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
    InputStream is = testConnection.getInputStream();
```

The strange thing as I mentioned is that ab.exe tests runs fine:

```
 c:\work\dotera\servers\apache\bin>ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://localhost:8080/testWeb/test
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.0.40-dev <$Revision: 1.146 $> apache-2.0
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Copyright 2006 The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:        WildFly/8
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /testWeb/test
Document Length:        108 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   5.302303 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      3620000 bytes
HTML transferred:       1080000 bytes
Requests per second:    1885.97 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       530.230 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.530 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          666.69 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0  12.2      0     998
Processing:    56  478 316.6    320    1319
Waiting:        9  320 327.2    198    1291
Total:         56  479 316.7    320    1319

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    320
  66%    326
  75%    841
  80%    847
  90%    893
  95%   1302
  98%   1310
  99%   1314
 100%   1319 (longest request)

c:\work\dotera\servers\apache\bin>
```

I think this might help understanding the nature of the problem.

One more thing to mention is that running the same tests agains a node.js client with java client and ab.exe gives 0% failiure.

==========================================================================

I made another test. What I changed is to put nginx in front of the wildfly to better understand the requests. The java test again threw "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" and what is interesting here is that nginx does not register the failing requests at all.

Here is the scenario:

1. access logs of the nginx are empty.
2. I make 1100 requests from java threads started together.
3. I have 177 requests from the client which throws "java.net.ConnectException"
4. In the nginx access logs I have 923 requests registered with HTTP CODE 200 - OK and I have no other requests registered.

This gives me the idea that there is some problem with opening client sockets from the same machine in java. Maybe there is no ptoblem with Undertow, it is just the client which is failing.

The mystery for me was why the same test running against nodejs didn't failed, but after several runs  it failed on a pure nodejs HelloWorld with "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect".

The conclusion for me is that there is a problem with the client which runs under java. There is no problem with Undertow (Wildfly/8.1)

Comment: This information is helpful.. I will try and get back to you.. Thank you